# How to manage "pools of resources" in Microsoft Project 2016?

Tags: ms-project

I need to create multiple pools of resources (each containing interchangeable resources within). To clarify I need a pool of front-end developers, another of back-end developers, and a pool of testers. Each pool has temporary contractors that come and go from the project at different dates. Then, for example, I will have some Tasks that assigned to front-end only, whilst other as a mix of front-end and back-end.

I Googled this issue without luck. Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Usually a 'resource pool' is created to share the same resource among multiple files.  Is that your intention?  Same people, shared across multiple projects?

Comment: Nope. My intention is to have a group of equivalent resources assigned to a task and I would like MSP to assign the first free one to complete the task.

Comment: I am afraid you are destined for disappointment. :-) Microsoft project will never assign resources.  You can use resource leveling to reschedule tasks when an assigned resource is available

Answer (score -1):

Try create a resource with its own calendar and a max capacity of 400%, 500% or whatever.

This is the way several pools of resources work in Project. For example, you can make a resource called "Testers", value 500% for 5 testers. Then, you can assign your task to that pool.

A pool of resources is when all resources in a pool have the same calendar and the same cost. If not, you don't have a pool, because you have a differente restriction in your project for each member. You need a cost and time baseline.

Comment: How does that solve the problem?

Comment: I'll explain better.